# How can I restart my Python Arcade game so that it works properly after game over?

Tags: python, arcade

I'm working on a simple platformer game in Arcade with a player and an enemy.

If the player collides with the enemy, I would like the game to start over from scratch.

However, with my current code, I call setup() and the game resets, but I am unable to move my player and the enemy doesn't move either. Please help!

```
        if len(arcade.check_for_collision_with_list(self.zombie, self.enemies)) > 0:
        self.game_over = True

    if self.game_over:
        self.score = 0
        self.setup()
        self.update()
```

Comment: This isn't really answerable as a general question, at least not within the scope of Stack Overflow. How you solve the problem depends on how the rest of the code is structured. If you want ideas for good ways to structure games so that they're "restartable", you should look for a tutorial - Stack Overflow is not the place to help you.

Comment: Check out in the official documentation if you can find some useful examples. This question as Karl Knechtel said is not really answerable. https://arcade.academy/examples/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you remember to set `self.game_over = False` after restarting?

Comment: Like the Zen of Python says: `In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.` If someone asking a question didn't provide enough information, you should post a comment to point that out, and vote to close as appropriate (usually, community specific -> needs debugging information).

Comment: I would've posted this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Oof. Yeah, I'm not a fan of the bootstrapping involved with the reputation system here. The best I can advise is to just stick to the clear questions for now.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel , I apologise. I am new to Stack Overflow and will make more effort to write clearer questions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide enough information, but the problem should be that some variables didn't reset when you called setup(). So that's what you need to do

Comment: Like the Zen of Python says: `In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.` If someone asking a question didn't provide enough information, you should post a comment to point that out, and vote to close as appropriate (usually, community specific -> needs debugging information).

Comment: I cant post comments with 1 reputation. I would